# Preventing students from leaving educationClass Teams?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-edu

As the official Microsoft provided PowerShell module for working with Microsoft Teams does not provide a way to create a Team using the `educationClass` template, we developed our own script to create Teams for situations where the group did not already exist in our MIS system (and was therefore not in SDS).

This script uses a mix of the MS Graph API and the PowerShell module and up until recently we have not had any problems. However we've now had a report that a student was able to leave one of the Teams we created using this script. We were led to understand that students could not leave class teams, so we reported this to Microsoft support, but were advised that they considered this a "developer issue" rather than a bug, so they directed us here.

The PowerShell code snippet in which we actually create the Team is as follows:

```
$body = @{
"template@odata.bind"="https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('educationClass')"
    "displayName"=$teamname
    "description"=$teamname
}
$bodyjson = ($body | ConvertTo-JSON)
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams" 
                -Body $bodyjson -ContentType "application/json" 
                -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $accesstoken"} -Method Post
```

(with the last 3 lines being all one line)

We then add students to the Team using `$result = Add-TeamUser -GroupId $groupId -User $userId -Role Member`

We checked the student in question using the MS Graph API but they definitely have `primaryRole` set to `student`, so we suspect the issue is with the Team. Is there something we missed out or didn't get right when creating the Team or when adding the students?

Comment: One note, while the `primaryRole` property is populated by School Data Sync, it is not a required field (you can create an `educationUser` with no `primaryRole` via Graph). I also don't believe Teams is looking at `primaryRole`.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur what I'm suggesting is that there's some additional thing that SDS does when creating Teams to make them so that students cannot leave them, which we are not doing in our process (because we don't know what it is).

Comment: Currently we don't have a feature that block the student from leaving the class. There is a [feature request](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/34609684-prevent-member-from-leaving-a-team) could you please go there and upvote it?